# Statements in "if block" are executed before function in "if condition" returns

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I wrote the below code in Android. The function "confirmalert" actually displays an alert box and has positive and negative buttons.

But always the "else" part is working, that too even if I haven't selected anything.

Please reply with how to make it work properly.

```
private void updatestockin()
{
    if(confirmalert())
    {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
}
```

My `confirmalert` function:

```
public boolean confirmalert(String title,String msg)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {
                flag=false;
            }
        });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: `confirmalert` is not blocking, thus, always returns true immediately-

Comment: the funnction confirmalert which you are calling in if condition doesn't have parameters. Is it calling different function?

Comment: The `OnClickListener` is where you're supposed to put the code that runs when the user clicks a button. Move the code you want to run into the appropriate `onClick` method.

Comment: @Shuddh, I have removed that so you guys can to understand the code easily. The code is actually working. But the problem is, the else part is working even before I select anything in the alertbox.

Comment: @AKSW I didn't get you. Can you please explain

Comment: I think there is an async issue. So maybe this alert in different thread. So since your flag is initialized false, it runs that.

Comment: Have you tried adding another if where (confirmalert()) is false so you would have the other case around? If true then A, if false then B ?

Comment: @Shuddh Thats what I think too, But I need a solution to make the " if part" wait till the confirmalert completes.

Comment: @E.J check my answer

Comment: @E.J What I meant is that Java isn't waiting until something happens inside the dialog - it's just executing the code linearly, that means the dialog will be created, shown, and then immediately the value of `flag` will be returned.

Comment: wait, where the "flag" field/variable is defined?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch as a private variable inside the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an async issue. So maybe this alert in different thread. So since your flag is initialized false, it runs that.

So using wait() and notify() you can sync the threads
Try this:

```
public boolean confirmalert(String title,String msg)
{
    wait();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {
                    flag=true;
                    notify();
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {
                    flag=false;
                     notify();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    wait();

    return flag;
}
```

It should work. not tested. If possible read about wait and notify a bit to properly understand, hope it takes you to right path.

Comment: I'm not actually looking for alternatives. I need to make the main part wait till the method completes

Answer (score 2):

The confirmalert() method returns immediately (before the AlertDialog is even displayed on screen) with the value of the **flag** field which is false if not set otherwise in your class. That happens because AlertDialog.show() is asynchronous, otherwise it would block the main (ui) thread and you would not be able to interact with the app any longer after calling it.

What you need to do is move the call to **confirmalert()** outside of **updatestockin()** method and call updatestockin from the Dialog.OnClickListener().

```
 //call this from where you normally call updatestockin()
 confirmalert();
 //updatestockin(); // comment this call as it will happen after the user clicks one of the AlertDialog buttons

private void updatestockin(boolean flag) {
    if (flag) {
       Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       t.show();
   } else {

       Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       t.show();
   }
}


public boolean confirmalert(String title,String msg)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {
                    updatestockin(true);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {
                    updatestockin(false);
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    return flag;
}
```